# Using filter in a query with 2 ManyToMany fields in Django

Tags: django, filter, many-to-many, field

I'll try my best to describe what I'm trying to do here.
I have 3 classes:

- Question
- QuestionType
- QuestionTemplate

And the relations are:

- Question <-ManyToMany-> QuestionType
- QuestionTemplate <-ManyToMany-> QuestionType

So the query is in a method inside QuestionTemplate that gets me a list of possible questions that have the same QuestionType that are related to the QuestionTemplate.

I've tried:`questions = Question.objects.filter(type__in = template.type.all())`
Where "template" is a QuestionTemplate object.
But this query returns to me the Questions that have at least one QuestionType inside the QuestionType list from template.
What I want to do is get the have exactly the same QuestionTypes in both question and template.

I tried many things, but cant get this to work, please, somebody save me!

Comment: please clarify what you are trying to get. You are trying to get the questions that are exactly the same in the ...? I think you left a couple words out of your initial post.

Comment: I want to get the questions that have the same(exactly) connections to QuestionType on a given QuestionTemplate.
So if I get a template that has the QuestionType = (Type1, Type2 and Type3)
The query would return all the Questions that hava the connections to QuestionType = (Type1, Type2, Type3).

So any other question that has a different connection to QuestionType, like(Type1, Type2 and Type5) wouldn't enter the list..
The same goes to one question that has the QuestionTypes = (Type1 and Type2), since it doesn't have the Type3 like the template, it would also be cast out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
types = template.type.all()
query = Question.objects
for t in types:
    query = query.filter(type = t)
questions = []
for q in query.select_related('type'):
    ok = True
    for t in q.type.all():
        if t not in types:
            ok = False
            break
    if ok:
        questions.append(q)
save_questions_in_m2m_relations_so_that_you_dont_have_to_repeat_this(questions)
```

Quite clumsy, but should do what you need.

Comment: Speaking in performance, is it better to do it only using filter/exclude instead of an iteration over a list checking wich one is OK?

Comment: @Arruda: Filter/exclude does all the calculations in the database, so this is always is faster, often by a factor of ten. But I couldn't think of a solution in pure filter/exclude. Maybe you could do it in raw SQL. But **before you optimize**, make sure that it is in fact a performance bottleneck. Could save you a lot of time if it isn't.

Comment: The main reason I want to know this is because I want to learn how to face a problem like this...
this resolution would fit well the problem I have now, but maybe in the future I face another one that can only be handled with querys so I wanted to know how to do it that way.